# Restart a PC with Synology NAS task

Tags: script, synology

I would like to have a script for Synology NAS task manager that can restart a PC in the local network.

Comment: You want a NAS to reboot some other computer? Why would you think that this is possible?

Comment: This isn't a free script writing service. Show us what you have tried and the research that you have done.